# PHP 7 FPM slow log file location

Tags: logging, php-fpm, php7

In my www.conf file, there is this line:

`slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow`

Where is that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*: probably at `/var/log/php7-fpm/www.log.slow`.

The `$pool` variable is set from the configuration section name at the top of that same file. Since the file name is `www.conf`, I'd bet the pool name is `www`, specified on the top line of the file like so: `[www]`. (So far, I can't find how we end up in `/var/log/php7-fpm`.)

Comment: Ok I'll give this a go and see what I find.

Answer (score 0):

```
slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow
```

This setting creates a file in a /usr directory. We had issues with it because of permission errors.

Because it's not fully determistic we just define an absolute path to /var/log/ which is where we want to store the files:

```
slowlog = /var/log/$pool.log.slow
```

$pool will be by default be replaced by "www" but can be configured different when desired.